# Get a value from a string in an array at a specific character?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an array of values that i need to parse through and extract the values to a new array based off a certain character

eg value: `2012-04-19T19:21:07-08:00`

I want to loop through an array populated w/ values like the above and extract everything from that value after the "T" from each position in the array and populate a new array with those results.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`substr()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) and [`indexOf()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) string methods you can achieve. Ex:

```
var x = '2012-04-19T19:21:07-08:00'
x.substr( x.indexOf('T') + 1 ); // output: "19:21:07-08:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var d        = new Date('2012-04-19T19:21:07-08:00');

var hour     = d.getHours();
var minutes  = d.getMinutes();
var seconds  = d.getSeconds();
```

There are a lot more features in the [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods)...